# Can DBA revoke access privilege from the owner of a table?

Tags: permissions, database-agnostic

If I create a table **T**, I become the owner of the table.

Can DBA access **T**?

Can DBA also revoke my access or grant privileges on **T**?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am not using any DBMS. I am just reading a book and this question came into my mind. The book follows SQL92. What happens in the DMBS you are most familiar with?

Comment: They all work differently but, broadly speaking, a user with DBA privs can do anything

Answer (score 1):

A user with DBA privillege(sysdba,super etc.) can do anything. He can access or grant privillege of any table or database objects.

Comment: What is a DBA privilege?  Do you mean something like `sysdba`, `sa`, `superuser`, `super` or similar?

Comment: yes the general privillege is this @dezso